# How to disable the code completion of image literal in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 8 supports color, image and file literal. When I typed a few characters, the code completion will suggest me with some picture. This really confused me for a long time. I want to know how to disable the code completion of image only. Or disable that three literal at the beginning. Please help me, many thanks in advance! 
[image]

Comment: Also this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744569/xcode8-is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-autocomplete-for-image-names